# How to grab videos from a database and display them on a webpage

Tags: xml, database, video, smil, web-development-server

I have a bunch of videos that I'm am storing in a MySql database (if another database or programming language would be better please let me know) and using php to grab them and display them on a webpage.  As far as I can see the best and most efficient way to store the videos is in a file on the server and then putting the location of the videos in the database.  I know how to query the database to get the location, I was just wondering how I take the location and use that to format and display the video on the webpage.  I was thinking of using XML or SMIL.

Could someone give me some ideas of how to do this or any better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support old browsers you can consider using [HTML5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp).

Based on [Browser share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers), and [IE version share](http://www.statowl.com/web_browser_usage_by_version.php?timeframe=last_6&interval=month&chart_id=4&limit%5B%5D=ie&fltr_os=&fltr_se=&fltr_cn=) This should give about 80% of users access to your videos.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - you shouldn' store the video's in the database. When you store the file locations in the database, pull out the file location, and using a server side language just insert the location into an html tag or a flash video players location attribute.